# what is return uri ionic3 for identity server 4?

Tags: oauth, ionic3, identityserver4, openid-connect

this is redirect uri for xamarin in identityserver4,

```
RedirectUri = "xamarinformsclients://callback",
```

source:

https://github.com/cloudscribe/sample-idserver/blob/master/xclient/XamarinFormsClient/XamarinFormsClient.Core/MainPage.xaml.cs

what is redirect uri for ionic in identityserver4 when usin in app browser.

```
const ClientId = "IonicClient";
const ClientSecret = "<SECRET>";
const RedirectUri = "http://localhost:8100/";
```

here is my uri now. but it return to this url not my apps
ionic cordova build android

Comment: Why cant you connect that error messages are you getting?

Comment: sorry, it return to localhost:8100 not my apps

Comment: i will fix my word

Comment: did you add it to the client on the identity server?  It might help if you post how you have created IconicClient.

Comment: "redirect_uri": "io.ionic.starter",      
"client_id": "IonicClient",      
"response_type": "token id_token",      
"state": "WJXbyxlvDI",      
"scope": "openid profile idserverapi offline_access",      
"access_type": "offline",

Comment: this is the response i change from localhost:8100 to io.ionic.starter still error

Comment: malformed redirect_uri: io.ionic.starter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect uri you set up in your client on the identity server must exactly match the one you are using in the client application.  You can just guess or make up a redirect uri you need to know where you want the return to go to.  Check the logs on the identity server it should tell you where the request is coming from and give you a clue as to what redirect uri you need to add.

```
"redirect_uri":"io.ionic.starter",
"client_id":"IonicClient",
"response_type":"token id_token",
"state":"WJXbyxlvDI",
"scope":"openid profile idserverapi offline_access",
"access_type":"offline",
```

You have set up `io.iconic.starter` you say your using `http://localhost:8100/`.   I sugst you updated it and add `http://localhost:8100`

Comment: after use http://localhost:8100 and do login 
it return webpage not avaliable
the webpage at
http://localhost:8100/#code=$$$$$$ code

Comment: can you help me when it return this value.

Comment: that would be the authorization code which you will need to exchange for your access token.      How to deal with that is a different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195649/ionic3-identity-server-4-inappbrowser-redirecturi-webpage-not-avaliable here is the new link please help thanks